# PHP Unlinking File - Directory Issue

Tags: php, file

I am trying to unlink a file but the PHP unlink function seems to refer to the directory of the script file I am using rather then where the file is.

I am using change directory (chdir) to change the directory and yet this is seemingly having no effect:

```
chdir("themes");
    $file_path = getcwd()."/".$_GET["file_path"]."/";
    $deleted_file=$file_path.$data["file_name"];
    $fh = fopen($deleted_file, 'w') or die("Can't open file");
    fclose($fh);
    unlink($deleted_file);
```

The error I get is the following:
Warning:  fopen(/home/mow/public_html/mysite/themes/_default/admin/testfile.php/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/mow/public_html/mysite/themes/_default/admin/file_manager.php** on line **223**

Comment: How are you calling this?  What are your values for $_GET["file_path"] and $data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your `'file_name'` GET variable ends with a slash. Try ensuring that isn't the case.

NB: Make really, really, really sure that nobody you don't completely trust will have the ability to access this script.

Comment: Thank's much very much that was what was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the trailing slash.

BTW: Why don't pass the path directly to `unlink` instead of using `chdir` then `getcwd`?